# concat two string columns in android room database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, concatenation

I need to concat two columns in query and compare it. this is my code. it doesn't work. I want to search full name. how to do that:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shohada_table WHERE name LIKE :searchKey OR family LIKE :searchKey OR (SELECT name || family  FROM shohada_table AS fullname ) like :orgSearch ORDER BY family ASC, name ASC")
fun getInfo( orgSearch: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, ShohadaItem>
```

in this query, I send `searchKey` in the form of `%SearchWord%"` and `orgSearch` will be the original word:  `SearchWord`. for example, if I want to search  `Linus Torvalds`, the `searchKey` will be `%Linus Torvalds%` and `orgSearch` will be `Linus Torvalds`.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: I use room database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and thanks for your responses. I got my desire result in the following query.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shohada_table WHERE name LIKE :searchKey OR family LIKE :searchKey OR (SELECT name || ' ' || family as fullname ) LIKE :searchKey ORDER BY position ASC, family ASC, name ASC")
fun getSearchedItems(searchKey: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, ShohadaItem>
```

if my search words be `mahdi noori`, my searcKey will be `%mahdi%noori%`. I use following code for this:

```
shohadaDao.getSearchedItems("%${searchKey.replace(" ", "%")}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (SELECT name || family  FROM shohada_table AS fullname ) you just need to use
name || family

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shohada_table WHERE name LIKE :searchKey OR family LIKE :searchKey OR (name ||  family) :orgSearch ORDER BY family ASC, name ASC")
fun getInfo( orgSearch: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, ShohadaItem>
```